# Trig substitution $\int x^3 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int x^3 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$$

$x = \sin \theta $

$dx = \cos \theta d \theta$

$$\int \sin^3 \theta d \theta$$

$$\int (1 - \cos^2 \theta) \sin \theta  d \theta$$

$u = \cos  \theta$

$du = -\sin\theta d \theta$

$$-\int u^2 du$$

$$\frac{-u^3}{3} $$

$$\frac{\cos^3 \theta}{3}$$

With the triangle trick I get:

$$\frac{-\sqrt{1-x^2}^3}{3}$$

This is wrong but I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: The first substitution leads to $\pm\int \sin^3\theta\cos^2\theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be just cos?

Comment: @Dantheman No, $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos\theta$ and $dx =\cos\theta \;d\theta$

Comment: I think you are mistaken. I get that x= sintheta, dx=costheta dtheta. Meaning dtheta = dx/costheta. Meaning the cos cancels out and I am let with sin. You forgot that part.

Comment: @Dantheman You have $x^3 \cdot \sqrt{1-x^2} \cdot dx$. you replace each factor with the corresponding result of the substitution $x \to \sin\theta$, and $dx \to \cos\theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: you should have $ \int \sin(\theta)^3\cos(\theta)^2d\theta. $

Comment: @DanielFischer But dtheta is = dx/costheta. So when I put the dtheta in I have to remove the dx and add a 1/cos which eliminates the cos.

Comment: But **you don't have a $d\theta$ to start with**. You start with a $dx$. And that $dx$ becomes $\cos\theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why does $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \cos\theta$? If $x = \sin\theta$ then $1-x^2 = 1-\sin^2\theta \equiv \cos^2\theta$. Then $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \sqrt{\cos^2\theta} \equiv |\cos\theta|$. For example, what happens when $\theta = \frac{5\pi}{4}$?

Comment: @FlybyNight Yeah, we tend to be a little lazy about such things, not saying so explicitly. Since we substituted freely, we can just say $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews "*we*"?

Comment: It's a pretty common substitution, hence "we" meaning "practically ever other person who has done the same thing, and myself." :) @FlybyNight

Comment: No, an infinite domain isn't really permissible, since $x\in[-1,1]$ so we can assume $\theta\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. @FlybyNight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\sin{\theta}$, then $dx = \cos{\theta} \, d\theta$; the integral becomes

$$\int d\theta \, \sin^3{\theta} \, \cos^2{\theta} = \int d\theta \, \sin^3{\theta} -\int d\theta \, \sin^5{\theta} $$

$$\int d\theta \, \sin^3{\theta} = \int d\theta \, \sin{\theta} (1-\cos^2{\theta}) = -\int d(\cos{\theta}) (1-\cos^2{\theta})= -\cos{\theta} + \frac13 \cos^3{\theta}+C$$

Similarly

$$\int d\theta \, \sin^5{\theta} = -\int d(\cos{\theta}) (1-\cos^2{\theta})^2 = -\cos{\theta} + \frac{2}{3} \cos^3{\theta}-\frac15 \cos^5{\theta}+C'$$

Subtracting the two, I get

$$\int d\theta \, \sin^3{\theta} \, \cos^2{\theta} = -\frac13 \cos^3{\theta}+\frac15 \cos^5{\theta}+C$$

Then use $x=\sin{\theta}$ and get

$$\int dx \, x^3 \, \sqrt{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{15} (3 x^4-x^2-2) \sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$

**EDIT**

I see that the answer can be simplified further to

$$-\frac{1}{15} (1-x^2)^{3/2} (3 x^2+2) + C$$

Comment: You seem to be apprehending identities out of thin air. Where did The first two lines come from? I don't follow at all.

Comment: @Dantheman: the only identities I use is $\cos^2{\theta} = 1-\sin^2{\theta}$ and d(\cos{\theta}) = -\sin{\theta} d\theta$.  The rest is algebra.

Comment: I don't see the identity. Why is sin cubed time cosin squared equal to integral sin cubed - integral sin to the fifth?

Comment: @Dantheman What Ron did was:
$$
\int \sin^3\theta\cos^2\theta d\theta = \int \sin^3\theta(1 - \sin^2\theta) d\theta = \int \sin^3\theta - \sin^5\theta d\theta
$$

Comment: @Dantheman: $$\sin^3{\theta} \cos^2{\theta} = \sin^3{\theta} (1-\sin^2{\theta})$$

Comment: Is that easier than doing the standard (1-cos^2x)^k cos^nx sinx dx? integral

Comment: I've cleared up the discussion about notation.

Answer (score 2):

What about by integration by parts? It looks pretty simple:

$$u=x^2\;,\;\;u'=2x\\v'=x\sqrt{1-x^2}\;,\;\;v=-\frac13(1-x^2)^{3/2}$$

and thus

$$\int x^2\cdot x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=-\frac13x^2(1-x^2)^{3/2}+\frac23\int x(1-x^2)^{3/2}dx=$$

$$-\frac13x^2(1-x^2)^{3/2}-\frac2{15}(1-x^2)^{5/2}+C$$

**Note:** We used above the following:

$$\int x(1-x^2)^k\,dx=-\frac12\int (-2x\,dx)(1-x^2)^k=-\frac12\frac{(1-x^2)^{k+1}}{k+1}\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all the trig by making a much simpler substitution:$$u^2=1-x^2$$so: $$x^2=1-u^2$$ $$ u= \sqrt{1-x^2}$$ $$2u du=-2xdx$$

Rewriting the integral, factoring out one $x$:$$\int x^3 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx=\int x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2} xdx=-\int (1-u^2) u^2 du$$Multiply out the integrand, integrate with the power formula term by term and substitute back for $x$...

Comment: I would prefer to use trig substitution since I need to learn it. If I wanted to do it the easy way I would have put it into wolfram alpha :P

Comment: Sure, but don't forget, part of learning an integration technique is learning when, and when not, to use it   :)

Comment: I tell everyone when this chapter comes to start learning their trig identities they forgot back in 10th grade, it doesn't hurt to prove some of them to oneself to understand where they all come from. I remember one time it saved me on a quantum mechanics assignment to remember the cotangent and tangent half angle identities.

Comment: There are too many to remember for a summer class.